# Select data to be shown in combobox or hide what I need

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So for my combobox I use `dataSource` which contains `ID`, `Name`, and a List with one element which I need when I want blank selection. Right now when I open my combobox I see this:

[image]

`--No Material--` comes from the list like that :

```
materialTypes.Insert(0, "-- No Material --");
```

and I need it, but the `ID's` and the Names come from another list generated with Linq query and I want to hide the ID's. I don't know what's the approach - hiding the data I don't need or explicitly marking the data which I need. But I don't know how to do either of those two things.

P.S This is the whole code for the combobox :

```
 IList<String> materialTypes =  ((from tom in context.MaterialTypes
                                                where tom.IsActive == true
                                                select tom.Name)
                                           .Union(from tom in context.MaterialTypes
                                           where tom.IsActive == true
                                           select SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)tom.ID))).ToList();

            materialTypes.Insert(0, "-- No Material --");
            cboTypeOfMaterial.DataSource = materialTypes;
```

Comment: Show us the code you currently use to populate your combobox.

Comment: My post is edited with the code being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your query it is a bit strange, I would do it like that:

```
IList<MaterialType> materialTypes =  (from tom in context.MaterialTypes
                                      where tom.IsActive == true
                                      select tom).ToList(); //do you really need to split ID's from Names?

materialTypes.Insert(0, new MaterialType { Name = "-- No Material --" }); //add to our list fake material

combobox.ValueMember = "ID";
combobox.DisplayMember = "Name";
combobox.DataSource = materialTypes;
```

Comment: You are perfectly right. If you know how much time I spend for the `UNION` query... But thanks, your way is far much better.